# VueJS to do list - handling clear event on input

Tags: javascript, beginner, event-handling, to-do-list, vue.js

I made a basic to-do list in VueJS, but it feels really clunky and obtuse to me. One of the key things is that if the text input value is empty and the user clicks the button labeled *submit* then it shows a red error. When you start typing, it goes away. I tried declaring the variables in a different scope but it breaks the application. See full sample below:

```js
// components
Vue.component('todoitem', {
  template: "<li>Test Item</li>"
})

// app code
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [],
    button: {
      text: 'Hide'
    },
    seen: true
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      let item = document.getElementById("list-input").value;
      let error = document.getElementById("error");
      if (item == "") {
        error.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        app.todos.push({ text: item });
        error.style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    removeItem: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    },
    removeError: function() {
     let item = document.getElementById("list-input").value;
      let error = document.getElementById("error");
     if (item == "") {
        error.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        error.style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    toggleSeen: function() {
      app.seen = !app.seen;
      app.button.text = app.seen ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  width: 900px;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.todo-list {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.todo-list__delete {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .todo-list__delete {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Add an Item to the list</h3>
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
      <a v-on:click="removeItem(index)" class="todo-list__delete" href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input v-on:keyup="removeError" type="text" id="list-input">
  <input type="submit" id="list-submit" v-on:click="addItem">
  <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none;">Please Enter Text</span>

  <ul>
    <todoitem></todoitem>
  </ul>

  <h2 v-if="seen">SEEN</h2>
  <button id="hide-seen" v-on:click="toggleSeen">{{ button.text }}</button>
</div>
```

How can I make this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###DOM references
If you are using functions to lookup DOM elements (e.g. `document.getElementById()`) for elements contained within the root element (or component), it might likely be the wrong way of doing things, as far as VueJS code goes. With VueJS, you can use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) to bind the value of the input to a data property - for example, the `<input>` for the new list item can have a `v-model` attribute added, like:

```
<input v-on:keyup="removeError" type="text" id="list-input" v-model="newItem">
```

And it would be wise to add an entry in the `data` object for that model value:

```
data: {
    todos: [],
    //...
    newItem: ''
```

Then when creating an item, use `this.newItem` for the value.

###Conditional Rendering
The error message can be conditionally rendered using `v-if` (or `v-show`, depending on how the DOM should be laid out in various cases). Read more about [conditional rendering here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

That way there is no need to lookup the DOM element and set the *style* to `display: block`, `display: none`, etc.

###Method context
In the method `toggleSeen()` the variable `app` is used, but realize that the method is called in the context of `app` so `this` can be used instead (of `app`).

###Computed properties
Use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to control values that depend on other values. For example, the button text can be added to a computed property. Remove `button` from `data` and then add a computed property:

computed: {
button: function() {
return {
text: this.seen ? 'Hide' : 'Show'
};
}
}

That way the logic for the *text* property can be removed from the method `toggleSeen()`. Then that method call could be replaced by an inline expression, or else a checkbox could be used with the `v-model` attribute bound to `seen`.

```js
// components
Vue.component('todoitem', {
  template: "<li>Test Item</li>"
})

// app code
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [],
    seen: true,
    showError: false,
    newItem: '',
  },
  computed: {
    button: function() {
      return {
        text: this.seen ? 'Hide' : 'Show'
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      this.showError = (this.newItem == "");
      if (!this.showError) {
        app.todos.push({
          text: this.newItem
        });
        this.newItem = '';
      }
    },
    removeItem: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    },
    removeError: function() {
      this.showError = false;
    },
    toggleSeen: function() {
      this.seen = !this.seen;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  width: 900px;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.todo-list {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.todo-list__delete {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .todo-list__delete {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Add an Item to the list</h3>
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
      <a v-on:click="removeItem(index)" class="todo-list__delete" href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input v-on:keyup="removeError" type="text" id="list-input" v-model="newItem">
  <input type="submit" id="list-submit" v-on:click="addItem">
  <span v-if="showError" id="error" style="color: red;">Please Enter Text</span>

  <ul>
    <todoitem></todoitem>
  </ul>

  <h2 v-if="seen">SEEN</h2>
  <button id="hide-seen" v-on:click="toggleSeen">{{ button.text }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to review.